# Understanding decision flow in a react-redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to understand the application flow in a react-redux application with respect to login.

- The application state maintained by redux contains a boolean called `loggedIn` that is initially `false`.
- Based on the state `loggedIn` being `false`, the main application screen shows a login panel containing `username` and `password` fields, into which the user enters credentials.
- The `login` button on the login panel calls an action creator, passing in the credentials.
- The action creator starts an asynchronous AJAX call to the server's login API.
- A promise middleware, like redux-promise, intercepts the promise and replaces the action's payload with the response from the server. Meanwhile, the server checks the credentials and returns either "200 Ok" or "401 Unauthorized", as appropriate.
- The action reducer checks the response in the action payload and sets the value of the `loggedIn` state as appropriate (`false` for "401" and `true` for "200").
- The main application screen renders the login panel again if the `loggedIn` state is `false` or the "successfully-logged-in" panel if it is `true`.

Does this flow make sense? Is this the idiomatic way to handle login in a react-redux single-page application? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I think the general flow makes sense, I would add two more items:

1. Save the auth token to local storage, otherwise you will be logged out if you refresh the page, because loggedIn will be reset to false. You'll then need to reload the token when the app restarts and verify the token is still valid.
2. I would also have a loginErrorMessage to display any error response from the server.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.